# Cs vs cshtml.cs in asp.net RazorPage

Tags: razor-pages

I accidentally left the presentation model class file in Razor Pages with the extension .cs instead of .cshtml.cs. On a simple example, it works. Are there any pitfalls to this solution other than breaking the naming convention. And why did Microsoft make such an agreement? After all, .cs looks much cleaner and more practical than .cshtml.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another value for the `*.cshtml.cs` naming convention is that it provides insight into the contents of the class file, in much the same way that JavaScript files are named.

Using the [three.js project](https://threejs.org) as an example, the main file has [multiple versions](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build):

- `three.module.js`
- `three.module.min.js`
- `three.js` (deprecated in v150+)
- `three.min.js` (deprecated in v150+)

All of these files are JavaScript files with the extension `.js` but the additional naming "extensions" provide clues for the *content* of the file: `three.module.js` is the ES Module version of the core `three.js` project. `three.module.min.js` is the minified version of the ES Module build. `three.min.js` was the minified version of the original pre-ES Module version `three.js` file.

A `/Pages` folder in a Razor project can have the following:

- Index.cshtml
- Index.cshtml.cs
- Index.cs

The naming convention of `Index.cshtml.cs` provides insight that this class file has a page model declaration and is associated with a Razor view file.

The file `Index.cs`, if in the same folder as `Index.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml.cs` can have any content like a class model declaration used in `Index.cshtml.cs`. The file could be named this way to associate `Index.cs` with the Razor page.

Comment: So it's just a matter of conventions. In that case, as mentioned above, I would suggest the convention that the display model file (PageModel) has the same name as the Razor file (as it does now) and a cs extension. And also a convention that class or model files with the same name not directly related to the Razor file should not be in the same folder as that file. Which by unspoken agreement is what happens (Models folder and others).

Answer (score 0):

The *cshtml.cs* file is used to declare a PageModel class which is associated with a Razor page. It's just C# code so there is no technical reason why you cannot use a *.cs* file for this instead, as you have done.

The only practical downside is that you lose the file nesting support offered by IDEs that provide it, such as Visual Studio.

The naming convention is carried over from Web Forms, where the "code behind" (another C# class) had an *aspx.cs* extension and the view template had a *.aspx* extension.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your reply! What a coincidence, I'm reading your wonderful and useful book "aspnet-core-razor-pages-in-action" and my question came up while doing the example from this book. 

I mean, actually Microsoft could have made it a .cs extension (would have looked cleaner) and the file nesting support offered by IDEs would have been offered by the same file name.

Comment: @workwork Thanks for reading my book and glad you find it helpful. The ASP.NET team and VS teams are completely separate. I would guess that getting the VS team to revise the file nesting algo would have likely been more trouble than it was worth, given that existing devs are well used to the naming convention and most file names are generated by the scaffolder anyway. But you can always put in a feature request on Github.